# Advertise multiple 'Bonjour' hostnames for the local computer on Snow Leopard

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, bonjour, mdns

I am developing an in-house solution for which I need to register a couple of additional bonjour hostnames for the local machine besides the one assigned through the 'sharing' System Preferences pane. I don't know if it's possible to do so by means of an existing configuration file for mDNSResponder, through a command line utility (akin to mDNS for registering services) or if should I use the Bonjour API for it.

Answer (score 1):

'RendezvousProxy' can advertise any services.

http://ileech.sourceforge.net/index.php?content=RendezvousProxy-News